# Django append <queryset> for searching each words in a sentece using filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to search each word in a sentence and put that in `result['post']` dictionary 
and of course this code only looks for  last query

```
queries = querystring.split()
    for query in queries:
        results['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query)
```

i tried `append`,`extend` and a lot of things but it didn't work as expected.

**Edit Update:**
I also tried

```
    count = {}
    results = {}
    post_results = []
    queries = querystring.split()
    for query in queries:
        post_results.append(Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query))
    results['posts'] = post_results
    count['posts'] = results['posts'].count()
```

But this leads to another error `count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFT09.png)

Also `Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query)` this line returns a queryset value and [Queryset type of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/) doesn't seem to have append. Is there it's own append like feature ? If so then that  wouldn't change it's queryset type to list. Using `temp` variable like `post_results = []` changes to list.

Can we change that list back to queryset? If we can then that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you I tried everything mentioned at first and finally got a solution
*I did a crazy thing at first*.
I wanted to define an empty queryset so for `results['posts']` so I did a bad but a working way
 `results['posts']=Post.objects.filter(text_icontains='sth_that_will_never_b_true')`
and I used

> [Django Merge QuerySets](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/06/20/django-tip-5-how-to-merge-querysets.html)

and solved the problem and then later studied genuine way to define empty QuerySet as

> [django.db.models.query.QuerySet.none](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.none)

And gladly final code is

```
count = {}
results = {}
results['posts']=Post.objects.none() # empty QuerySet
queries = querystring.split()
for query in queries:
    results['posts'] = results['posts'] | Post.objects.filter(
        text__icontains=query)

count['posts'] = results['posts'].count()
```

Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is `results['posts']` value is overwritten per every for loop..

How about changing code like

```
queries = querystring.split()
tmp = []
for query in queries:
        tmp.append(Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query))
results['posts'] = tmp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had tried that,too. I just updated the question about further error count() function. @Damotorie

Comment: How about fixing `post_results.append(Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query))` to `post_results += Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
results = {'posts': []}
count = {'posts': []}
for query in querystring.split():
    qs = Post.objects.filter(text__icontains=query)
    results['posts'].append(qs)
    counts['posts'].append(qs.count())
```

---

Update after you answered your own question:
Oh, I was under the assumption you wanted a list of queries of each word with their respective result counts. If you only wanted to combine each string of the search term into an OR query you could use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
results = {}
count = {'posts': []}

from django.db.models import Q
qobjects = Q()
for query in querystring.split():     
    qobjects |= Q( ('text__icontains',query) )
 results['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(qobjects)
 counts['posts'] = results['posts'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks but this also leads to same error of count()

Answer (score 1):

instead of making multiple queries we can use Q object, here is the simple example

```
q = 'query string'
keywords = []
prevword = ""
for word in q.split(' '):
    prevword = prevword + word + " "
    keywords.append(prevword.lower())

query = Q(title__icontains=q)
for keyword in keywords:
    query.add(Q(title__icontains=keyword), Q.OR)

services = Service.objects.distinct().filter(query).all()
```